# How to create an activity with side panel in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to create an activity with a side panel. More precisely, i want an activity similar to Google Play Store app (i.e. if swiped left-rigt, a panel opens).

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: I didn't even knew the name of this! Please stop down voting! It's been 2 years for heavens sake....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called `navigation drawer`.

I'd suggest read up on it on official site, it has even a sample app you could try it on.

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: or you can research it as hamburger menu